# changing the embed's footer

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i have this code that would change an embed's footer and resend it to the log channel, but now it doesn't work anymore for somereason

this is the code:

```
if message.channel == bot_commands_channel:
    for em in message.embeds:
      em.set_footer('''new footer''')
      await log_channel.send(embed=em)
      return
```

and this is the error i get:

```
File "main.py", line 297, in on_message
    em.set_footer('''new footer''')
TypeError: set_footer() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: are you on the latest discord.py version because from the latest version it tasks 2 kwargs and here you just gave a peramiter as for today [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.set_footer) you can also give an icon_url maybe try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for `set_footer` is keyword-only:

```py
embed.set_footer(text='''new footer''')  # note the `text=...`
```